# In THREE.js, how to map one texture to a 3D rectangle

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, textures

I'm trying to make a box in THREE that represents a box of 2x4 Legos, 24 pieces wide by 48 pieces long and and arbitrary number of pieces tall. I've generated a texture that shows this pattern using random colors:

[image]

I need to show two sides this cube, but the textures have to align so that the pieces on the edges are the same colors, like so (generated in Blender):

[image]

I'd really prefer not to make six images for a CubeTexture, particularly since four are not visible. Is it possible to flip the texture on one side so that they appear to align? (We're just going for visual effect here.)

Further, not all 3D rectangles will be cubes, but I can't quite figure out how to set the `texture.repeat.x` and `texture.repeat.y` so that the x is scaled correctly and the y is at the same scale, but just cuts off when the height of the object ends, like so:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flip an image by flipping the UVs.

You'll need to figure out which UVs correspond to the face you're trying to mirror, and which direction to flip them (not sure how your geometry is created).

Here's an example using a basic `BoxBufferGeometry` and modifying its `uv` attribute. (The face on the right is the mirrored-by-UV-flipping face.)

```js
var textureURL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/Triangular_hebesphenorotunda.png";
// attribution and license here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Triangular_hebesphenorotunda.png

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.setSize(500, 500);

var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(50, 25, 50);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);

camera.add(new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity));

var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 20, 20);
var uvs = cubeGeo.attributes.uv;
// originally:
// [0] = 0,1
// [1] = 1,1
// [2] = 0,0
// [3] = 1,0
// convert to:
// [0] = 1,1
// [1] = 0,1
// [2] = 1,0
// [3] = 0.0
uvs.setX(0, 1);
uvs.setY(0, 1);
uvs.setX(1, 0);
uvs.setY(1, 1);
uvs.setX(2, 1);
uvs.setY(2, 0);
uvs.setX(3, 0);
uvs.setY(3, 0);
uvs.needsUpdate = true;

var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: "white",
  map: textureLoader.load(textureURL, function(){
    animate();
  })
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, mat);
scene.add(mesh);

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! For me, I just needed to rotate the top, like so: 
           `var OFFSET = 8;
           uvs.setXY(3 + OFFSET, 1, 1);
     uvs.setXY(2 + OFFSET, 0, 1);
     uvs.setXY(1 + OFFSET, 1, 0);
     uvs.setXY(0 + OFFSET, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create six `PlaneBufferGeometries` assign the same material, and then position them to form a cube. Rotate them in 90deg increments until you reach the desired result. For performance reasons, you could merge these back into a single `BufferGeometry`.

Comment: Well these are all basic classes and basic concepts (scene graph). Either looking at the docs or `how to get started` would be a good starting point.

Comment: Maybe imagine if you you started flattening your box, like the terminator ends up in the first movie. Eventually it will be so flat that it will look like a plane. You have to move this up (or down, left right, depending on which axis you flattened it). You have to figure out how far to translate it etc hence it makes no sense to give you a specific code example. `myBox.scale.z = 0, myBox.position.z = -5` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the model you made in blender, either using the THREE.js json exporter, or a format like OBJ or GLTF, and load and render it directly.

What you are talking about is simply having the UV's laid out the way you have them in blender.. so if you need that level of control.. it's probably easier to just load the model instead of trying to generate it.

If you use either three.js .json or .gltf, both exporters have an option to embed the textures directly in the export. This can make it easier to get things working quicker, at the expense of possibly less efficient storage.